# Power series calculation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to find an analytical expression of the series:
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{N}a^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
where $a$ is a real number?
If we have:
$$S_{\infty}=\lim_{N\to\infty}S$$
is $S_{\infty}$ 
convergent for any $a\in\Re$?

Comment: It will not be convergent except for $a=0$.

Comment: Hint: What is $\lim_{k\to\infty} a^{1/k}$?

Comment: @Jim Conant: in fact I don't know if it's possible to define $\lim_{k\to\infty}a^{\frac{1}{k}}$

Comment: @Raskolnikov: why?

Comment: If you're not sure about the convergence of $\lim_{k\to\infty}{a^{1/k}}$, try calculating some examples and see if you can guess whether the limit exists and if so what it is.

Comment: Maybe it would help to rewrite it as $e^{\frac{1}{k} \cdot \text{ln} a}$.

Comment: Is it for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, or do you also assume that $a > 0$?  I guess it doesn't matter in the end, but the case $a < 0$ has to be handled a bit more carefully when computing $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a^{\frac{1}{k}}$.

Comment: @Nicholas Stull: maybe we can consider only the case $a\ge 0$

Comment: If $a = 0$, then $a^{1/k} = 0$, $\forall k$.  So the series does converge at $a = 0$.  Now, let $a > 0$.  To compute $\lim_{k\to\infty} a^{1/k}$, find $\lim_{k\to\infty} \ln(a^{1/k}) = L$, and then $\lim_{k\to\infty} a^{1/k} = e^L$.  We would then conclude that $\lim_{k\to\infty} a^{1/k} = 1$, $\forall a > 0$.  (This result would not be as quick to compute if $a < 0$, but I'm confident it is still true, by expressing $a = |a| e^{i\pi}$, and continuing in a similar manner.)